# Align four elements without empty space for content blocks with css

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem to container 4 blocks with different height in one place.

You can see my demo by link https://jsfiddle.net/inthedark122/ncvjaeqy/1/

HTML Code:

```
<div>---- You can change only css styles!!!</div>
<div>---- height - height - what is affixed is for understanding the content, in the original height is unknown in all cases
We know only width = 48 for ga и fa, the content on the right (f and g) should occupy all the remaining space as done in the example</div>
<div>
---- The content of 4 blocks at any time may change, because these 3 cases must be considered as one, but at a different time
</div>

<div>There shouldn’t be any empty space between f and g, there shouldn’t be any space between fa / ga, you need to stretch g to f to fill this spaceо</div>
<div class="root">
  <div class="fa">fa</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
  <!-- <div class="g-root"> -->
    <div class="ga">ga</div>
    <div class="g">g</div>
  <!-- </div> -->
</div>

<div>
  Empty space should not be between f and g, between fa / ga empty space should be, ga should be on the same level with g
</div>
<div class="root">
  <div class="fa">fa</div>
  <div class="f" style="height: 150px;">f</div>
  <!-- <div class="g-root"> -->
    <div class="ga">ga</div>
    <div class="g">g</div>
  <!-- </div> -->
</div>

<div>
  The height of the lower blocks should be aligned with the maximum height ga or g
</div>
<div class="root">
  <div class="fa">fa</div>
  <div class="f" style="height: 150px;">f</div>
  <!-- <div class="g-root"> -->
    <div class="ga" style="height: 200px;" >ga</div>
    <div class="g">g</div>
  <!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.g-root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.fa {
  height: 128px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: grey;
}

.f {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  /* flex: 1; */
  /* width: 100%; */
  width: calc(100% - 48px);
  /* margin-left: 48px; */
  /* margin-bottom: 128px; */
}


.g {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.ga {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  /* margin-top: -128px; */
}

.fa, .ga {
  width: 48px;
  color: white;
}
```

I try absolute position and float, but I got empty space between  f and g or block "ga" was not be on same line with g.

Please check all comments in my demo to better understand my problem

**UPD1:**

Main goal is remove empty space between f and g (right side). When I do this, I get two issue:

- blocks for fa and ga get on each other
- when panel **f** more then panel **fa** then panel **ga** not in the same line with **g**. For this case we need empty space between **fa** and **ga**

**More details**

The object is represented by 4 rectangles.
There are 3 possible object States at different time intervals. They are presented in the Example.

The rules must be followed:

1. there should never be an empty space between f and g (in all three examples). You need to stretch g to f to fill this space.
2. If the height f is greater than fa, there should be an empty space between fa and ga.
3. If the heights of ga and g are different, then they should stretch to the maximum of them.

Note: 
only CSS can be edited. html is forbidden to touch.

Comment: not able to figure out what needs to be done, please add some clear descriptions...

Comment: main goal to remove empty space between content block (right side - f and g)

Comment: I updated my description with more information, thanks for feedback

Comment: Working on it, I think I got it what I needed...

Comment: I updated description in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q7krytf8/2/

Comment: Can you just try removing fixed height `height: 50px;` for class `.f`.
I think that should solve your problem. If not, you can try grouping `.f` and `.fa` in one `div`  and `.g` and `.ga` in another.

Comment: Remove height: 128px; from .fa https://jsfiddle.net/an5s7d28/1/

Comment: @NiteshPhadatare The entire height represents the content in each block. I have dynamic content in all blocks, for example I can have textarea in ```.f``` block and someone can increase height of the textarea. The height of the block ``` .f``` consists of blocks of children.

Comment: @MattJHoughton I can not do this, I have dynamic height between 0 and infinity. height = 128px is an example to understand content in this block

Comment: @inthedark122 This will work with dynamic heights - https://jsfiddle.net/wkqczj9v/ . Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MattJHoughton for ```fa``` the height can also be dynamic (for example I have collapsed panel with 3 or 1 buttons)

Answer (score 0):

I have done the required changes, I think you need to play around with the `flex` property for other examples. Hope this helps -:

https://jsfiddle.net/e96cprb2/

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
}
.a-root{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.g-root{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 5;
}
.fa{
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  
}
.ga{
  display: flex;
  background: grey;
  flex: 1;
}
.f{
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1
}
.g{
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  flex: 5
}
```

```html
<div>---- You can change only css styles!!!</div>
<div>---- height - height - what is affixed is for understanding the content, in the original height is unknown in all cases
We know only width = 48 for ga и fa, the content on the right (f and g) should occupy all the remaining space as done in the example</div>
<div>
---- The content of 4 blocks at any time may change, because these 3 cases must be considered as one, but at a different time
</div>

<div>There shouldn’t be any empty space between f and g, there shouldn’t be any space between fa / ga, you need to stretch g to f to fill this spaceо</div>
<div class="root">
  <div class="a-root">
    <div class="fa">fa</div>
    <div class="ga">ga</div>
  </div>
  <div class="g-root">
    <div class="f">f</div>
    <div class="g">g</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Empty space should not be between f and g, between fa / ga empty space should be, ga should be on the same level with g
</div>
<div class="root">
  <div class="a-root">
    <div class="fa">fa</div>
    <div class="ga">ga</div>
  </div>
  <div class="g-root">
    <div class="f">f</div>
    <div class="g">g</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  The height of the lower blocks should be aligned with the maximum height ga or g
</div>
<div class="root">
  <div class="a-root">
    <div class="fa">fa</div>
    <div class="ga">ga</div>
  </div>
  <div class="g-root">
    <div class="f">f</div>
    <div class="g">g</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @inthedark122 let me know what else needs to be done... we can do it in private chat...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/inthedark122/pz0ew6ru/1/ for this case (with additional textarea) the block ```ga``` should start on the same line with ```g```

Comment: p.s. height for textarea is an exampe

Comment: Why do you remove example height for ```fa```? try height for `fa` between 0px and 128px. When you set height for `fa` = 128px and minimize height for textarea to 50px You will see empty space.

Comment: Please break your problem statement into 3 different parts and ask in 3 different blocks...., it is too much to be answered under same Question....

Comment: I can have 2 state of my panels:
1. I have fa (filter actions) with height 128px (3 buttons) and filter panel with one field (~50px), in this case I see empty space between g and f (this is my issue), and I want to remove it
2. `fa` = 48 px (1 button) and `f` have 3 fields (~150px). In this case I want to see ga (grid actions) and g (grid) on same line. This is my problem to resolve 2 state in one css/html code

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try removing fixed height `height: 50px;` for class `.f`. I think that should solve your problem.

If not, you can try grouping `.f` and `.fa` in one `div` and `.g` and `.ga` in another.

Like shown in this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ah6f5ozx/4/

Comment: The entire height represents the content in each block. I have dynamic content in all blocks, for example I can have textarea in ```.f``` block and someone can increase height of the textarea. The height of the block ``` .f``` consists of blocks of children.

Comment: Please check the other solution in the fiddle.
I think that will help you.

Comment: Please also look at the fiddle.

Comment: I don't see links. What fiddle do you mean?